# Lync sets my presence to "Do not Disturb"

Tags: windows, lync

Lync 2013 on Windows 7 automatically sets my presence to "Do not Disturb" virtually every morning, within an hour or two after I log in. This always seems to happen during a period of time when I'm working in some other application. The Microsoft FAQ about Lync/Outlook presence indicates no situations under which this particular presence indicator will be automatically chosen.

Is there any setting that could be causing this?

Comment: I seem to remember Lync working off Outlook's calender for its statuses...do you have a calender event for that period of time?

Comment: Nope, calendar is clear. It uses "In a meeting" for that condition, and that works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually  learned why this happens. The context menu you get when clicking on the Lync icon in the system tray is a custom menu that contains small, unlabeled colored dots for setting your status. It turns out I would often accidentally click on the red one when dismissing this menu, changing my status without meaning to.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the `Gear` icon above the `Find Someone` search bar. Then go to `Tools -> Options`

Click the `Status` tab.

You should see at the bottom `Show me as Do Not Disturb when I present my desktop` and `Show me as Do Not Disturb when my monitor is duplicated`

Make sure both are unchecked.

Comment: They are, sadly, both already unchecked!

Comment: What's your Sign in As status before you sign in?

Comment: I logged out and looked; it was "Available".

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one device signed in to Lync it can get the MS servers *very* confused. Messages can go to one device and not others, and, I suspect, statuses can also get muddled. Could this be the cause?
(I find Lync to be a very disappointing piece of software, but it appears, unfortunately, to be adopted by many organizations, presumably for the sake of convenience as it forms part of Office 365.)